# Why does my TSC keep crashing when using MUI props

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I am currently converting a Next.js and Material UI JavaScript project to TypeScript.

Here is the code for one of my components, and whenever I specify `Props` as an intersection type (with MUI's `BoxProps`), the TSC freezes and live type-checking seems to stop:

```
import { Box, BoxProps, SxProps } from '@mui/material'

type Props = {
  onSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent) => void
  children: React.ReactNode
  sx: SxProps
} & BoxProps
//       seems to be causing freezing

export const Form = ({ onSubmit, ...props }: Props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onSubmit(e)
  }

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Here's the error message thatI get stuck with:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I've sinced noticed that it works fine if I exclude `SxProps`. When the two are used in the intersection type together, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue when using MUI on a really huge monorepo project. This error will be only in `development` environment and not in `production` environment. It is caused by the way you are importing MUI components.

What is happening here when you import MUI component using `tree shaking` like this

```
import { Box, BoxProps} from '@mui/material'
```

Now it loads all the MUI modules and picks up `Box` and `BoxProps` out of it. Which makes the typescript compiler to freeze or slower some times.

As you can check here in [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#development-environment). First line says,

> Development bundles can contain the full library which can lead to
> slower startup times

So it is advised to use `path imports` instead of `tree shaking`

```
import Box, { BoxProps } from '@mui/material/Box'
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this was the problem, actually. I've since been informed that `BoxProps` already contains `SxProps` and their unison was causing the TSC to crash. I hope that helps too. Thanks, though.

Comment: Good finding! I have a similar scenario in a few components e.g. `type TextFieldBaseProps = { sx?: SxProps<Theme> } & TextFieldProps`. But I'm not getting the error/warning. Generally when we use the same name while combining two types, If the type is not the same, it changes it to the type `never`. So it could be due to using `SxProps` instead of `SxProps<Theme>`.